# How do I draw a semi-transparent rectangle in Qt?

Tags: c++, qt, user-interface

I'm trying to draw a semi-transparent rectangle on top of an image to act as a highlight.  Unfortunately, nothing I try seems to be able to perform the transparency effect I want.  Instead I just get solid filled rectangles, with no transparency.

Here's what I'm doing right now:

```
void PageView::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    QImage img=...;

    painter.drawImage(0, 0, img);
    ...
    // draw a light blue, transparent rectangle to highlight
    QRect rect=...;
    painter.fillRect(rect, QColor(128, 128, 255, 128));
    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, for me, this draws a **solid** blue rectangle, instead of the semi-transparent one I expect due to giving the `QBrush` an alpha value.

I've also tried drawing to an intermediate `QImage` or `QPixMap`, playing around with `painter.setCompositionMode(...)`.  No luck so far.

Thus my question: How can I convince Qt to draw a semi-transparent rectangle to my `PageView`?

**EDIT**: If it's relevant, I'm building this under Qt 4.8.1 on Windows.

Comment: There's no `QBrush(r, g, b, a)` constructor in the [Qt docs](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/4.8/qbrush.html).  Did you mean `QColor`?

Comment: I did, yes.  My mistake.

Comment: Full `PageView::paintEvent` at http://pastebin.com/Dj9dDd0c.  Though I don't think there's anything interesting in what I omitted.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The code works for me with a slight modification as it does not compile as you have it:

```
painter.fillRect(rect, QBrush(QColor(128, 128, 255, 128)));
```

**NOTE:**

The OP was painting the semi transparent rectangle in a loop causing the same area to be painted multiple times. This will result in an additive effect which will eventually cause that area to look the same as a solid fill.

Comment: Rightio, typeo in my question submission.  But this produces solid rectangles for me, not semi-transparent ones.

Comment: Have you tried the calling `fillRect()` as I have it here with a `QBrush`?

Comment: It looks like you are painting in a loop there. If you paint that semi transparent rectangle on the same spot multiple times, it will eventually be solid.

Comment: yup, that was exactly the problem.  Thanks for your help!